# Enzyme: how to test a key down?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a React application that reacts to a keypress of Escape. 
This is the code in the application:

```
componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction.bind(this), false);
    }
```

In the test code I write the following statement:

```
wrapper.find('document').simulate('keyDown', {keyCode: 27});
```

I got an error:

> ```
> Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
> ```

I also tried:

```
wrapper.simulate('keyDown', {keyCode: 27});
```

and it seems that application didn't react to escape click.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error **Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.** means the container is not found.

You should check this first to ensure you are getting the node:

```
const container = wrapper.find(".class_name");
expect(container.length).to.equal(1);
```

or this maybe be loading asynchronously that's why, you are not getting the node. Then you should try with **setTimeout** function to get the node.

Inside setTimeout function call this:

```
container.simulate('keydown', {key: 'Escape', keyCode: 27, which: 27});
```

May be this helps.